# Convert Sharepoint Designer 2007 workflows to Visual Studio solutions

Tags: 2007, workflow, visual-studio

Does anyone have experience or know of how to convert workflows created in SPD 2007 (moderate complexity -10 steps) to Visual Studio?

[This blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/porting-sharepoint-designer-workflows-to-visual-studio) almost has the answer except for the caveat **it doesnt work for workflows that have forms** which mine do.

Thanks for your help,
Nav

Answer (score 1):

Once question would be how soon do you plan on upgrading to SP 2010?  In SP 2010, there is an easy path for this.  SPD workflows can be exported as WSP packages and then imported into visual studio.

One thought which may or may not work would be to setup a virtual machine, upgrade your site collection to sp 2010, export it the workflow using spd 2010 and then import into vs 2010.  From there you can try to downgrade it for sp 2007.

From what I understand is it's a big pain to do this in SP 2007 and it is not supported.

Comment: Steve, unfortunatley no immediate plans for an upgrade to 2010. 
It is unsupported in SP2007 and is rather tedious but from the link I posted it seems possible. Just would really like to know how to do it with workflows that have forms! :)